# For Loop in R: Error in y[[j]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, loops, bounds

I am trying to calculate a value and insert the result into a results list.  Next, I'd like to use the previous result as an input, run calculation using previous result, and insert into new result into the results list.

```
x = seq(1,10, by = 1)

y = list()

i = 2

j = 1

for(i in 1:10){

y[i] = (x[i] - y[[j]])/2

i = i +1

j = j + 1
}
```

Comment: Since your `y` is a list, you'd change `y[1` to `y[[1]]=`, generally you can rely on `for` to do your counting for you (so the i=i+1 is unnecessary) , but it is unclear what you hope to accomplish with an uninitialized/undefined `y` (which without an enclosing for loop leads you directly to  `y/2 Error: object 'y' not found`. So the 'x-y' part that is going into y[[i]], y has to be something, which is?

Comment: `y[i]` to `y[[i]]`, typo.

Comment: `y` is an empty list...so anything in it is `NA`, which I think is giving the error

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ? :

```
x = seq(1, 10, by = 1)
y = list()
i = 2
j = 1
for(i in 1:10){
    y[[i]] = (x[i] - y[[j]])/2
    # i = i+1 unnecesary 
    j = j + 1 
}
```

As others advised this led to error due to uninitialized list.

Now works, but is kinda strange:

```
x = seq(1, 10, by = 1)
y = list()
i = 2
j = 1

# initialize y with random stuff
for(i in 1:10){
    y[[i]] = rnorm(5) # fill with 5 random values
}

for(i in 1:10){
    y[[i]] = (x[i] - y[[j]])/2
    # i = i+1 unnecesary 
    j = j + 1 
}
```

Please note that `i = 2` is meaningless since its value is overriden by both loop indexes, which are named the same.